# Multiple Backbone.js collection options?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Intro:**

Building in node.js and express on the backend, I am sending a `res.json(details)` to the `localhost:3000/me` route containing the users session information.

So that on the client side I can work with that specific user, for example on the client side initialization I write some code like this.

```
var me = new MeModel();   
me.fetch({
    success: function(response) {
        App.data.me = me;
        var messages = new MessagesCollection([], { id: response.get('user_id') });
        messages.fetch({
            success: function() {
                App.data.messages = messages;
                App.core.vent.trigger('app:start');
            } 
        }); 

    }
});
```

You see I fetch the `me` model and use that to filter the messages in the `MessagesCollection`.

---

**Question:**

In my `MessagesCollection` I pass options like this.

```
module.exports = MessagesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.id = options.id;
    },
    url: function() {
        return '/api/messages/' + this.id;
    },
    model:  MessageModel,
    //url: '/api/messages'
});
```

This is great for getting the desired models when using `var messages = new MessagesCollection([], { id: response.get('user_id') });`

My question is when somewhere else I run `window.App.data.messages.create(Message);` this wants to POST to `/api/messages/:id` when I want to POST to the regular collection?

**Theory:**

So obviously I would say the best thing is to rethink how I filter the models in the fetch method.

So basically to simplify this question I need to filter the collection upon `.fetch()` **GET**... and set no filters upon `.create()` **POST**

BTW I am using marionette, maybe that can help with something?

Answer (score 0):

> model.url()  Returns the relative URL where the model's resource
>   would be located on the server. If your models are located somewhere
>   else, override this method with the correct logic. Generates URLs of
>   the form: "[collection.url]/[id]" by default, but you may override by
>   specifying an explicit urlRoot if the model's collection shouldn't be
>   taken into account.
>
> Delegates to Collection#url to generate the URL, so make sure that you
>   have it defined, or a urlRoot property, if all models of this class
>   share a common root URL. A model with an id of 101, stored in a
>   Backbone.Collection with a url of "/documents/7/notes", would have
>   this URL: "/documents/7/notes/101"

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url

So you can define method url at MeModel and generate url there ( if there are no other users - you can just return string "/me" or generate in based on model properties ( for example switch if model has id )